# How to load dotenv config and initializeApp only once in firebase function second generation

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have to load dotenv config and admin.initializeApp methods in every function file. Precisely, I have to write below code in every file:

```
import { config } from "dotenv";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
config();

if (!admin.apps.length) admin.initializeApp();
```

Is there a way to write this code only in index file and all functions get access to env variables as well as app get initialized in all functions.

Comment: Instead of index, why not have a single separate module to include that exports the shared data to use wherever these are needed?

Comment: @DougStevensonSo, I have extract it in function and call it on every firebase function. It is not possible to write this code only once in index. Right?

Answer (score 0):

you can centralize the initialization code for dotenv and Firebase Admin in a single file (for example, index.js) and then import that file in your individual function files. This way, you don't need to repeat the initialization code in every function file.

Here's an example of how you can structure your files:

Create an index.js file:

```
// index.js
import { config } from "dotenv";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

config();

if (!admin.apps.length) {
  admin.initializeApp();
}

export { admin };
```

Import in your function files:
Now, in your individual function files, you can import the index.js file to access the initialized admin instance.

```
// your-function-file.js
import { admin } from "./index";

// Now 'admin' is available for use in this file.
```

This way, the initialization code is centralized in the index.js file, and you only need to import the admin instance in each function file where you need it.

Remember to adjust the paths in the import statements based on the actual directory structure of your project. This approach helps in keeping your code DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) and makes it easier to manage the initialization logic across your project.